# How to calculate slope of line if lines are perpendicular?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geometry

There are two points `lastPoint` and `prePoint`. They determine a line.
I try to calculate slope of this line using this:

```
    let kbase = (lastPoint.Y - prePoint.Y) / (lastPoint.X - prePoint.X);
    let bbase = lastPoint.Y - kbase * lastPoint.X; //y = kx + b -> y - kx;
    let ybase = `${kbase} * x + ${bbase}`;
```

So, if `Y` are equals then `kbase` is zero, it means straight line equation is `y = b`.

After that I try to calculate slope of perpendicular line to the first line, but I get error, because `1 / kbase` where `kbase == 0`.

```
    let kh = -1 * (1 / kbase);
    let bh = startPoint.Y - kh * startPoint.X;
    let yh = `${kh} * x + ${bh}`;
```

How to find a slope of perpendicular line if line equation is `y = b`?

Comment: You require a method to find slope of a vertical line .The slope of a vertical line is undefined.

Comment: Perhaps store angles instead? Then you won't have to deal with undefined values.

Comment: What do you mean about store angles?

Comment: Instead of calculating the slope, calculate the angle of the line using the Math.atan2 function. Depends what you are going to use it for though.

Comment: I try to find the coordinates of attitude of triangle from start point to the trinagle base. I know all vertex coordinates.

Comment: If you already have coordinates, can't you just find the largest and smallest `y` positions, and subtract those to get a height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explicit form of a line equation, `y = mx + p` does not allow to represent verticals, as the slope is infinite.

For your purposes, you can use the implicit form, `ax + by + c = 0`, which does not have this problem. An orthogonal line can be given the equation `bx - ay + d = 0`.

Comment: How to apply this formula in my case? I mean how to get x, y of this line?

Comment: @Gogol: write it down and you'll see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the slope of a vertical line is undefined. This is just how it works mathematically, and there are no problems with your code, and your math is correct. As you have realized, a horizontal line is a function that follows the form y = ox+b and its slope is 0. The perpendicular line of a horizontal line results in a vertical line which is not a function. This means that there are several values of y that correspond to one value you of x. Here is why that is important.

The general way of calculating slop is the change in y over the change in x.
Because a vertical line is not a function, there are multiple y's for one x. Here is an example. Let's say that we had the equation x=5. Here are some points: (5,1),(5,2),(5,3)(5,7). If you calculated slope with the first two points, it would result in (2-1)/(5-5) which is 1/0, and if you calculated slope with the last two points,
it would result in (7-3)/(5-5) which is 4/0. If you continued to do this, you would have an infinite number of undefined values for the slope of a vertical line. Keep in mind that 1/0 does not necessarily equal 2/0 or 6/0.Even if you tried to find a horizontal line and take the inverse reciprocal, which you did, you would not be able to find a defined value.

For example, if slope is the change in y over the change in x, then the inverse reciprocal would be -1 * the change in x over the change in y. Let's say that we had the horizontal line y = 0x + 5. The coefficient of the x or slope is 0. Four points would be (5,5), (9,5), (3,5) (6,5), and the two slope calculations for the slope of the perpendicular line would be 4/0 and 3/0 which leads to the same situation as last time.

To conclude, the answer to your question "How to find a slope of perpendicular line if line equation is y = b?" is that there is no defined value for the slope of a perpendicular line, and you definitely wont find one through the code you are using.